Is the pre-remaster era still appreciated and can it be re-invented?
Things are changing. My first self produced album was on an early 2000s 4 track recorder with live guitar, bass and drums gpro tab and record on DAW. Now I have integrated the old track recording process with record in on more advanced DAW.

I retain the late 70s to 90s live but clear and tight quality sound for the most part because that is what feels good to me. Integrated with other methods I can use for all sorts of projects but I have to be what you hear on my track, even if a studio artist plays what I composed live instrument to represent what I play. Anyone else share this? 


Hi Ryan, welcome to Music Fans. Can you please [edit] your question to make it more objective by focusing on a particular, 'measurable' issue (not "does anyone share this?" but something like "is this still common practice?") and to correct some of the phrasing?
